# Using UINavigationController view

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I would like to better understand the use of UINavigationController's.

I have setup a new project with a UINavigationViewController, as well as two other view controllers.

In my app delegate I have the following:

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

firstViewController = [[NCTFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NCTFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
navController = [[NCTNavViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Within my UINavigationController.m file I can set the title and set up buttons, but this does not work.

This only works if I setup the self.navigtionController items in the actual View Controller itself. Is this correct, or is there something I should be doing in the UINavigationController to get this to work.

Ideally I am looking for a UINavigationController that handles all the pushing to other controllers. In the long run it would be used as a menu system. So if the user clicks a button at the top, they are pushed to a new View Controller but without the back option, simply the same menu items in the navigation bar at the top, which shows a new center view controller.

The issue I am having is understanding how this is setup. If I have to setup this in the view controllers itself, would they all not duplicate the same code. Of course I could setup all the 'movement' in the AppDelegate, but this doesn't seem correct and would pack up the App Delegate itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [UINavigationController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it says (emphasis added by me, but you should read it all so that you understand how this works):

> **Updating the Navigation Bar**
>   When the user changes the top-level view
>   controller, whether by pushing or popping a view controller or
>   changing the contents of the navigation stack directly, the navigation
>   controller updates the navigation bar accordingly. Specifically, the
>   navigation controller updates the bar button items displayed in each
>   of the three navigation bar positions: left, middle, and right. Bar
>   button items are instances of the UIBarButtonItem class. You can
>   create items with custom content or create standard system items
>   depending on your needs. For more information about how to create bar
>   button items, see UIBarButtonItem Class Reference.
>
> The bar button item on the left side of the navigation bar allows for
>   navigation back to the previous view controller on the navigation
>   stack. The navigation controller updates the left side of the
>   navigation bar as follows:
>
> - If the new top-level view controller has a custom left bar button
>     item, that item is displayed. To specify a custom left bar button
>     item, set the leftBarButtonItem property of the view controller’s
>     navigation item.
> - If the top-level view controller does not have a
>     custom left bar button item, but the navigation item of the previous
>     view controller has a valid item in its backBarButtonItem property,
>     the navigation bar displays that item.
> - If a custom bar button item is
>     not specified by either of the view controllers, a default back button
>     is used and its title is set to the value of the title property of the
>     previous view controller—that is, the view controller one level down
>     on the stack. (If there is only one view controller on the navigation
>     stack, no back button is displayed.)
>
> The navigation controller updates
>   the middle of the navigation bar as follows:
>
> - If the new top-level view controller has a custom title view, the
>     navigation bar displays that view in place of the default title view.
>     To specify a custom title view, set the titleView property of the view
>     controller’s navigation item.
> - If no custom title view is set, ***the
>     navigation bar displays a label containing the view controller’s
>     default title. The string for this label is usually obtained from the
>     title property of the view controller itself.*** If you want to display a
>     different title than the one associated with the view controller, set
>     the title property of the view controller’s navigation item instead.
>
> The navigation controller updates the right side of the navigation bar
>   as follows:
>
> - If the new top-level view controller has a custom right bar button
>     item, that item is displayed. To specify a custom right bar button
>     item, set the rightBarButtonItem property of the view controller’s
>     navigation item.
> - If no custom right bar button item is specified, the
>     navigation bar displays nothing on the right side of the bar.
>
> The
>   navigation controller updates the navigation bar each time the top
>   view controller changes. Thus, these changes occur each time a view
>   controller is pushed onto the stack or popped from it. When you
>   animate a push or pop operation, the navigation controller similarly
>   animates the change in navigation bar content.

So, to do what you want, you do need to set the title and buttons in each view controller.  The easiest way to set the title is to set it in the storyboard/xib, or in code when you create it.

You should also **replace** the root view controller instead of pushing the view controller onto the navigation stack so that you don't keep adding view controllers to the stack.  This also avoids displaying the back button, and you won't need to explicitly get rid of it.  You would do this by using the `setViewControllers:animated:` method like this:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theNewViewController] animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this confirms my thinking. I am able to push the view controller onto the navController using the setViewController. The main issue/concern is that I then have to setup the exact same methods through out the majority of my controllers. For example if I have 6 menu items shown using a Side View Controller table view, when an item is selected the new view controller is pushed to the Nav, but I then have to duplicate the same code to display the menu again in each controller - just seems like there must be an easier way?

Comment: You can create a UIViewController subclass that contains all of the shared logic, and then subclass that for each view.

Comment: Also - the above setViewControllers only appears to work if I add the code in the AppDelegate and make a call to the app delegate method from the table view. Adding this to the table view code .m file itself doesnt change anything    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:accountViewController] animated:NO];

Comment: This should work.  Where did you place this code?  (I.e. which function?)

Comment: Thanks you are right in this example it does work I apologize. I have a more complex question which it would not work within - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236904/uinavigation-pushing-a-new-root-controller/13237950#13237950 - I will of course award this answer as its spot on, thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is only one NavigationController and this NavigationController controls all the ViewControllers. So barButtonItems and titles are set in each ViewController, you should not set them directly to a NavigationController.

If you want to push a new ViewController and won't push back, I think this may cause some problem because the NavigationController is using a Stack to handle all the ViewControllers. Seems that you will push a ViewController in the stack but not pop it, and maybe you will get some behavior you don't want.

If you still want to implement this, I think you cannot avoid do similar setting in different ViewControllers.