# Issue while presenting viewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I have a `configurationControllerVC` and `loginPageControllerVC`. Initially I want to present the `configurationControllerVC`. Once my configuration procedure is completed, I go to the `loginControllerVC`. If the configuration is already done and the user re-opens the app I want to load the `loginControllerVC` straight away without having to go through the configuration procedure.

The problem is that in my application, there is one condition and if it is false I want to take the user back to `configurationControllerVC`.

My flow of viewControllers is as below:

If configuration is not yet Done:

```
ConfigurationControllerVC --> LoginControllerVC --> HomePageControllerVC --> ReportingControllerVC.
```

If Configuration is done then the flow is this:

```
LoginControllerVC --> HomePageControllerVC --> ReportingControllerVC.
```

The condition on which I want to navigate the user to `configurationControllerVC` may be encountered on `HomePageControllerVC` or `reportingControllerVC`.

In such a case what is better? Using a `UINavigationController` or just presenting the Views one above the other? Also, how do I achieve this part of navigating the user back to `configurationControllerVC`?

Currently I am using this code to present the `configurationControllerVC` and `LoginControllerVC` in my `appDelegate`.

```
if ([self checkForConfiguration]) {

 // Initiate initial screen
    ConfigurationController *configurationController = [[ConfigurationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ConfigurationPage"
                                                                                                 bundle:nil];

    [self.window setRootViewController:configurationController];
}else{

    LoginController *loginController = [[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginPage" bundle:nil];

    [self.window setRootViewController:loginController];
}
```

Have seen these links but neither are working in my case:

1. [Changing root view controller of a iOS Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774003/changing-root-view-controller-of-a-ios-window)
2. [UINavigation pushing a new root controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236904/uinavigation-pushing-a-new-root-controller?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a `UINavigationController`, where the `loginController` is the rootViewController, where you can then push to the `homePageController` and `reportingController`.

And whenever your condition is met for `[self checkForConfiguration]`, present that over the top of the `UINavigationController`?

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:configViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: What do you mean by presenting the ConfigurationControllerVC over the top of UINavigationController? Can u be more specific. I am new to ios @Jeff

Answer (score 0):

I'm with @Jeff about using a `UINavigationController` as the window root view controller.

For your 'special' transitions (config -> login, login -> home, any -> config, because you don't want the user to be able to go back), instead of using push or pop, use `setViewControllers:animated:`. You'll get a nice animation are replace the navigation controllers root view controller.

For your home -> reporting you can just push onto the navigation controller stack as usual.